# VFD Driving a 40HP Inverter Rated Motor showing high Torque, Output Current at Low Speed

Tags: current, frequency, torque, vfd

I am having some difficulty troubleshooting a Toshiba VFAS3-4300PC. I am using it to run a 40HP inverter rated motor that is driving a VRU Screw Compressor. I have the frequency range set for 12-60Hz. When the VFD comes online and the speed command is reached the torque and output current are extremely high. If I leave the unit running too long, it shuts down on inverter overload. I have tried different V/F Patterns but none seem to bring down the torque and current output. I have increased the acceleration time to 300s. I am struggling on where to go from here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check the input and output voltages and currents?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will check this when I get back on shift